# why int() function not converting Number input into integer

Tags: python

```
import datetime

def random (start,stop):

    int(start)
    print(type(start))
    print(type(stop))
    print(type(num))
  
a = input("enter")
b = input("enter")
random(a,b)
```

I input to numbers and then that program should convert the first number (start) into integer but it didn't .
Thing I did't get is why is it showing that start variable is a string
I expected it to be an integer If I'm doing it wrong can you do correction
thank you

Comment: also where you initialised `num`  i don't see anywhere..

Comment: Since this is test code for stackoverflow, get rid of the prompts for input and hard code a call to `random`. Include the output you get and the output you want. That makes it easier to debug and include code in answers.

Comment: Did you notice the NameError exception that was raised when you ran this?

Answer (score 2):

`int()` is not changing variable in-place, so you forgot to assign its output

```py
start = int(start)
```